# Get true time in a certain time zone Swift

Tags: swift, time, nsdate

I understand that you can use `NSDate()` to get the current date, however, I need the true time of a time zone. By the true time I mean the standard time of an area, my problem with `NSDate()` is that the user can manually change the time in settings. This fundamentally destroys my app as it relies on all users having the same time. Is there a way for me to achieve this. Thanks.

edit: there are some other similar questions however none of them have answers that seem to work. The IOS NTP server 1. Is hard to implement with Cocoa pods (there seem to be no instructions) 2. It is slow, I have not yet implemented it but the NTP servers page itself says that it might take around a minute.

Would it be possible to write backend code into firebase that would get a standard time?

Comment: Look into accessing an ntp server.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated my question